# Remove other profiles from spring configuration file

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-profiles

I have application.yaml configuration file with few profiles:

```
server:
  address: 0.0.0.0
  port: 9090
db:
  url: 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/the_db'
  driver: 'org.postgresql.Driver'
  username: 'postgres'
  password: ''
---
spring:
  profiles: devArtem
db:
  url: 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db'
---
spring:
  profiles: prod_1
db:
  password: 'first_pass'
---
spring:
  profiles: prod_2
db:
  password: 'second_pass'
```

And I want to remove other profiles before build jar file. I don't want to give access for prod_1's password to prod_2 platform for example.

For prod_1 it must be something like this:

```
server:
  address: 0.0.0.0
  port: 9090
db:
  url: 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/the_db'
  driver: 'org.postgresql.Driver'
  username: 'postgres'
  password: 'first_pass'
```

or this:

```
server:
  address: 0.0.0.0
  port: 9090
db:
  url: 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/the_db'
  driver: 'org.postgresql.Driver'
  username: 'postgres'
  password: ''
---
spring:
  profiles: prod_1
db:
  password: 'first_pass'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple application-{profile}.yml and give each team the right file.

for example :

> application-devArtem.yml ---> to team devArtem
>   application-prod_1.yml   ---> to team prod_1
>   application-prod_2.yml   ---> to team prod_2